# How to make the framewok made for public use in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I had build a framework now I want to release it publicly like other framework like facebook and other. So I need to know the steps to do the same.
According to my understanding I need to build it using distribution. And then right click on the product -> show in finder.
Other question do I need to create a seprate distribution profile for it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Refer this link- http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

Comment: Also, make it available for CocoaPods and/or Carthage